# Custom javascript button error message

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I have a custom button and when the button is pressed the following javascript is executed:

```
window.parent.open(
    "{!URLFOR(
        $Action.Custom_Object__c.New,
        null,
        [
            CF00M0N00000OpQRx=Account.Name, 
            CF00NK0000001jyxH=TEXT(Account.Schedule__c), 
            CF00N2a000000b34C=Account.Custom_Number_Field __c
        ]
    )}", 
    "_self");
```

If I remove the `CF` from `00NK0000001jyxH=TEXT(Account.Schedule__c)`
I receive the following error message:

> Error: Syntax error. Missing field name

I do not see what is the reason of such error message.
Could you please advise what I can do to avoid such error message and solve my issue?

Comment: Probably complaining because it needs single quotes for values which cannot be resolved, try `'CF00NK0000001jyxH='+TEXT(Account.Schedule__c)`

Comment: It works with having `CF` why you wanna remove it? CF is the prefix for fieldAPIName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Pranay Jaiswal. I decided to keep the `CF`prefix